# explanation of Luci lua code from OpenwRT

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

I got a .lua code from /luci/controller/admin path

```
module("luci.controller.admin.network",package.seeall)
function index()
    local e
    e=node("admin","tab")
    e.target=firstchild()
    e.title=_("tab")
    e.order=60
    e.index=true
end
```

what is mean by `e.order=60` and  `e.index=true` ? How to add a new child category under tab drop down ?Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I got it . `e.order=60` means the position of the tab and `e.index=true` means you can add child elements